# DHTMLX Gantt does not render in background bootstrap tab

Tags: javascript, dhtmlx, gantt-chart

After upgrading from 4.1 version of DHTMLX Gantt to 5.2 I encountered a problem with rendering the chart in a 'hidden' non-active bootstrap tab. Even though div has HTML attribute width and height defined, the javascript height property returns 0 height. 
I tried to render gantt chart again on `onclick` event of a tab switch button, but it seems that transition effect does not display the div soon enough, so it only renders the gantt chart on the second button click, when the div is already displayed.

Did anyone solved this issue without writing an `shown.bs.tab` event listener?

Comment: The description of the problem does not help to understand why this is happening. Please create a ытшззуе and redirect the question to the DHTMLX forum in order to get a solution faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem should be fixed in gantt v6+
https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/whatsnew.html#x3174x60x3175x
Gantt now listens to its html container resize automatically.

Although, you may need settings `min-height` for gantt element if it doesn't have height specified.